# How do I use static files in a Django model's TextField?

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates

I need to display static content inside of a model's TextField.

I have tried marking the TextField as safe in the template, but it doesn't seem to interpret it like the rest of the the template tags, only displaying it as raw HTML.

From my template:

```
{{ project.content|safe }}
```

From my model:

```
content = models.TextField()
```

From my view:

```
class ProjectView(generic.DetailView):
    model = Project
    context_object_name = "project"
    template_name = "projects/project.html"
```

I'm expecting the content (`{% static "wdv101/koala/index.html" %}`) to display as a url to the static content, but instead it displays as {% static "wdv101/koala/index.html" %}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are trying to achieve is to use the string or project.content as template. Marking it as save means that e.g. Javascript is not escaped so that i will be executed. 
You could solve your "problem" with a [custom template tag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/howto/custom-template-tags/) that takes your content variable as input, renders it and returns the rendered html.

Custom template tag:

```
from django import template
from django.template import Template
from django.utils.html import mark_safe

register = template.Library()

@register.simple_tag(takes_context=True)
def in_template_renderer(context, template_string):
   template = Template(template_string)
   return mark_safe(template.render(context))
```

Using it in the template:

```
{% load in_template_renderer %}

{% in_template_renderer project.content %}
```

Do not forget to load required modules such as 'static' in your project.content.